# StatsManager throws Error on AddLocalUser

Tags: xbox-live

I am trying to use the C# StatsManager by first adding the localuser. My code is the following

```
XboxLiveUser user = new XboxLiveUser();
SignInResult x = await user.SignInAsync(); //returns successfully
statManager = StatsManager.Singleton;
statManager.AddLocalUser(user);
```

main loop:

```
List<StatEvent> statevents = statManager.DoWork
if (statevents.Count>0)
{

}
```

The local user added event never fires and instead it throws an error in the API which is the following. Throws an error on

getResponseCompletionSource.SetResult(getResponseTask.Result);

XboxLiveHttpRequest.cs
    Line 117

An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.))

what do you think could be the problem? The other API's work, able to sign in, get GamerTag and GamerPic from Socialmanager, etc...

also see screenshot[image: error in API]

Thanks

Comment: The only call that should me made when you call AddLocalUser on StatsManager should be to get the initial stats document (you can see that [in this source document](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api-csharp/blob/master/Source/api/Stats/Manager/StatsManager.cs#L83)).  It's possible that you need to explicitly publish your Xbox Live configuration first in order for this call to return successfully.  Can you go to your apps Xbox Live configuration in DevCenter and make sure to publish your configuration using the Test button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes I clicked the Test button, I also tried 15 minutes later as I've seen in other posts it takes some time to propagate into the system. Still same error. It is in fact crashing on GetStatsValueDocument. See two error screenshots [Link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AuO7AT-b2TAxhtZ6VoEjnePEOCAzvg) and [Link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AuO7AT-b2TAxhtZ7KqC_d5WV-TXGFg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can occur if there is something wrong with the `XboxServices.config` file loaded by your project.

Verify that the configuration file contains a `ServiceConfigurationId` property that's set to the appropriate value.

Note: If you use the Xbox Live Association Wizard it should automatically pull down the appropriate value and populate the `.config` file.